# Biblatex: How to manipulate citestyle/bibstyle?

Tags: biblatex

Do you have any advices how to costumize the citestyle (analog: bibstyle) in biblatex? Namely I want to replace e.g. `alphabetic` by `myAlphabetic` which results for

```
author = {Mihalas, Dimitri and Weibel Mihalas, Barbara}
```

not in `[MW84]` but in `[Mih1984]` or `[Mih84]`.

Always use 3 starting letters of 1st author; if its name is shorter, e.g. `Lu`, it should be something like `[Lu84]`.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's always the best to provide a complete minimal working example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a new style. The modification can be done by `\DeclareLabelalpha`. It is explained in the documentation at page 153ff and the definition is done in `biblatex.def`.

Related to your needs the following should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\renewcommand*{\labelalphaothers}{}
\renewcommand*{\sortalphaothers}{}
\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate{
  \labelelement{
    \field[final]{shorthand}
    \field{label}
    \field[strwidth=3,strside=left,names=1]{labelname}
  }
  \labelelement{
    \field[strwidth=4,strside=right]{year}    
  }
}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{short.bib}
@book{short,
 author = { Lu, LongLong },
 title = {Title of book},
 year=2013,
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{short.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{companion,short}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: After switching to another PC (also MikTex 2.9) your version is throwing errors: `\labelelement`, `\DeclareLabelalphaTemplate`, `\field` would be undefined control sequences. Do you have any ideas where this comes from? Without the redeclaration everything is fine...

Comment: @matheburg: you need an update. The version of MikTeX doesn't represent the version of any package.

Comment: Thanks - I guess you are right... my version is from 5/2012. Unfortunately, it seems to be unavoidable to reinstall full miktex distribution (which is not allowed here). Trying to upgrade just the `biblatex` package gives me a number of version conflicts and in turn a number of errors...

Comment: @matheburg: why is it unavoidable? Normally you can update all packages.

Comment: Which way you would prefer? Manually replacing the biblatex files by latest files from ctan and refreshing FNDB threw a bunch of errors and conflicts. On the other hand the package manager seems to be neither designed to update single packages nor it would be allowed to update in the case it would use its own connection to the server. Do you see different ways or did I miss something? Thanks again!

Comment: I don't work with windows. Maybe this can help you http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/how-should-one-maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation